# Boost::asio async_resolve is blocking

Tags: boost-asio

So I followed boost's tutorial for making an async http request located here:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp

My code is a direct copy outside of renaming and splitting into a h/cpp file.

Every method used is async yet when I try:

```
 resolver_.async_resolve(query,
        boost::bind(&client::handle_resolve, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));
```

It blocks for about 5 seconds before returning "Host not found".

Why is an async method blocking?

Comment: As I read through more documentation it might be io_service.run() that is blocking. In order for these to truly be async does io_service need to have its own thread?

Comment: the `io_service::run()` [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html) clearly states it is blocking. What behavior do you expect?